# SQL ORA-38104 on UPSERT with MERGE

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create an UPSERT query, which inserts a tuple in the `TEST` table only if one with the same CDN does not already exist, if this occurs an `UPDATE` is performed. Below is a snippet with one of many attempts made:

```sql
MERGE INTO TEST l
     USING (select :cn as cn from dual) ct 
     ON (ct.cn = l.CN)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET l.CN = :cn, l.LIVE_ENA = :liv_en, l.DATE_LIVE_UPDATE = :dtp
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (CN, LIVE_ENA, DATE_LIVE_UPDATE) 
    VALUES (:cn, :liv_en, :dtp);
```

But I always get the same error:

> ORA-38104: Unable to update columns referenced in ON clause: "CT"."CN"

Comment: It is not reproducible: https://dbfiddle.uk/YEkxpSEv. Or you misspelled `CN` as `CDN` which is pointless to update

Comment: You don't need to update that column. SInce it belongs to the `MATCHED` clause, you already know that the value matches your parameter.

Comment: I've corrected misspell

Comment: `merge ... ON (ct.cn = l.CN)` then `WHEN MATCHED` which means `ct.cn = i.cn` is true. So update here is not required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error says that you can't update columns involved in `ON` clause, so - remove it.

```
  MERGE INTO TEST l
     USING (select :cn as cn from dual) ct 
     ON (ct.cn = l.CN)               --> l.cn is used here ...
  WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
      -- l.CN = :cn,                 --> ... so remove it here 
      l.LIVE_ENA = :liv_en, 
      l.DATE_LIVE_UPDATE = :dtp
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (CN, LIVE_ENA, DATE_LIVE_UPDATE) 
    VALUES (:cn, :liv_en, :dtp);
```

Though, as we don't know which values you really used nor table description, there might be other error(s).